# How can i persist value in angular.js?

Tags: angularjs

**How can i persist user details in angularjs unless user logs out of the system?**

My header is using a variable called user, so when the user logs in successfully, i set the user attributes from REST response.Once , user is set then using ng:show and $scope.watch i change parts of the header and show welcome 'username'.
    The  issue comes when user again refreshes the page, in that case User is reset and user sees the landing page header.How can i correct it?How can i persist the User value unless user logs out of the system?Should i set user in rootScope or is there any other better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

This is an open-ended question and to really answer it, I'd need to know what your back end looks like and what your security requirements are.

I can see a two ways forward:

(1) If can rely on and trust cookies for security, you could just log the user in with data from cookies just like you log them in via the REST response.  The cool thing about this is that, to the user, it would be instantaneous (the next option won't be).

(2) Have a separate controller that handles the header that will always make a request to the server for  user data (logged in or not). [SEN](http://store.sonyentertainmentnetwork.com) does something like this (and it drives me crazy btw).  I don't know if you have a SEN account, but if you do, you could log in/out and try it out.  You'll see that when you hit the page initially, you get a loading screen, but even after that loads, the header even has a little "Signing in..." loading widget itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the local storage (a key-value pair HTML5 storage) to store the information and retrieve it on page load. There is a very simple library for this, if you don't want to write javascript yourself, called [Lawnchair](http://brian.io/lawnchair/). Otherwise google for html5 local storage tutorials.